# Get all value row selected in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I write the following code

```
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {

                }
                return true;

            }


        });
```

I Want, When I click in Coulmn 9 Get Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that I correct understand your question, but I suppose that you can just use [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method which get the data from the row in for of an object. The property of the object has the same names as the `name` property of the [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options):

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var rowData = $(this).jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
    ...
    return true;
}
```